# Shorthand javascript if else statement

Tags: javascript

```
if (lookfor.done == '1') {
    lookfor.done = '0';
} else if (lookfor.done == '0'){
    lookfor.done = '1';
}
```

How would I write a cleaner shorthand of the above in javascript?

Comment: What is unclean about that?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if `lookfor.done` is not '1' neither '0' ?

Comment: You have an `if` / `else if`, what's supposed to happen if both conditions fail? If that isn't something that can happen then why isn't it a `if` / `else`?

Comment: `done = done == '1' ? '0' : done == '0' ? '1' : done` but imo what you have is far better.

Comment: `lookfor.done` will only ever be either `"1"` or `"0"` that is why I have wrote it this way. I believed there would be a simpler way of putting it and it has been answered. Thanks to all, Big up to the person who voted down the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
lookfor.done = (lookfor.done == '1') ? '0' : '1';
```

<sub>(not accounting for values that are neither `'1'` nor `'0'`. If you need those, your double `if` is probably the best solution)</sub>

If you would use actual integers instead of strings, you could use an bitwise XOR shorthand assignment:

```
lookfor.done = 0/1;
lookfor.done ^= 1;
```

If you need the strings, you still can get shorter by using some unreadable magic:

```
lookfor.done = +!+lookfor.done+""; // cast: number, boolean flip, number, string
```

Maybe cleaner:

```
lookfor.done = String(1^lookfor.done); // XOR flip automatically casts to number
```

Comment: Well, that's shorter, I don't know about cleaner. It's rather harder to read.

Comment: Many programmers are used to seeing that. When working with a team of novices on a first programming project, verbose Visual Basic syntax, and clear blocks, tends to be easier; when working with senior programmers, labyrinthine C syntax probably won't go amiss. The debate of code complexity is a long one.

Comment: It's also not quite the same. The OP's code doesn't change `lookFor.done` if it isn't `'1'` or `'0'`. That could be pretty significant.

Comment: @Quentin: It's harder to read if you are not used to seeing it and it's certainly harder to read once you start nesting many levels, but for this simple case, I don't think it's too bad. The second suggestion, using xor, however is likely to throw many people for a loop.

Comment: You can also write in a cleaner way if your logic becomes a  little long by spreading the values over multiple lines.  ie.  The question mark and colon on separate lines under the assignment equal sign.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, but if that is a requirement then there's hardly an improvement possible. Maybe I should've stated that more clearly.

Comment: @Bergi: Edit's good (it was a minor comment in any case). I mean, you *could* go with `lookfor.done = lookfor.done == '1' ? '0' : lookfor.done == '0' ? '1' : lookfor.done;` but...yeech. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Totally clean solution:

```
lookfor.done = +!+lookfor.done+"";
```

Everybody will know what you mean.

But really. The default syntax for if-statements with curly braces is totally fine. Many people would agree if I said that there is no "cleaner" solution.

Explanation of the code, because someone asked for it:

First, the `+` right before `lookfor` casts the value to a number. Then, `!` negates it (!1 = false, !0 = true). The `+` before that casts the result back to a number (true => 1, false => 0). `+""` appends an empty string and casts the value back to a string.

**Note: Do not actually use this. Ever.**

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? I get most of it, but I don't understand the +!+ at the beginning.

Comment: @Bergi "Irony" - Look it up.

Comment: @TheSpooniest I added an explanation.

Comment: I'm upvoting this beauty!

Answer (score 0):

```
lookfor.done = lookfor.done == '1' ? '0' : '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

use this shorthand:

```
lookfor.done =lookfor.done == '0' ? '1':'0'
```

but much cleaner it would be with `boolean`:

```
lookfor.done=true;

lookfor.done=!lookfor.done;
```

Comment: '!' is a much quicker way of solving the problem in most languages however 'true' and 'false' do not convert directly to integers in ECMAScript (going the other way works though). There's also a further issue in that the supplied arguments are strings hence '0' is true.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a ternary statement, which is available in many languages.

```
lookfor.done === '1' ? lookfor.done = '0' : lookfor.done = '1';
```

You should have a fallback for when it's not equal to either... But why not just use booleans here? If you did you could simply negate the value like so:

```
lookfor.done = !lookfor.done;
```

This seems like what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

To account for the case where it's neither `1` or `0`:

```
lookfor.done = (lookfor.done == '1') ? '0' : (lookfor.done == '0') ? '1' : lookfor.done;
```

But it's pretty ugly to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unary` operator `+`.

```
var lookfor.done = !!your_value_here;
lookfor.done = !lookfor.done;
lookfor.done = +lookfor.done;
```

What it does is get the value as `integer` and turn it into a `boolean` with the `!!`.

- Then you switch the `boolean` value.
- Then you parse it as an `integer` again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a code-golfer, but using the ternary operator, I get this:

```
lookfor.done = lookfor.done * 1 ? '0' : '1';
```

`lookfor.done * 1` converts your string to a number: 0 for '0', 1 for '1', though it will also work for other numbers. The ternary operator then evaluates this as a Boolean (`false` for 0, `true` for anything else) and sets up the appropriate value, which gets assigned back into `lookfor.done`, as you ask.

But I'm forced to wonder: is this really cleaner than the `if`-statement? It will assign, not based on whether `lookfor.done` is '1' or '0', but on whether it's something which, if converted into a number, would equal zero. Strictly speaking, that's not the same check you're making in the question, though it may satisfy your needs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an exclusive OR (XOR) operation (though JavaScript only has the bitwise operator)

```
 lookfor.done = lookfor.done ^ 1
```